# GXT Palette in Eclipse kepler

Tags: gwt, gxt, google-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add GXT palete in Eclipse.[Using Ext GWT (GXT)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt)

I am not able to figure out where is **Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT**

Please help me to get the GXT palette in Eclipse.
Thanks

This is my screen[image: My Screen is look]

---

There is no Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using EXT GWT ,  [image: see the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Kepler There is no GWT Designer installed while installing gwt plugin.

For the GWT Designer

New GWT Designer builds which include this patch are available from the following update sites:

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.6

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.2

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3

**Use the 4.2 update site URL for 3.8. For Kepler use 4.3**

Note that these are update site URLs for use with the Eclipse update manager. They are not direct download links.

Also GWT Desinger only support 2.1.x and 2.2.5 (recommended , latest in 2.x.x series)

To download [GXT version 2.2.5](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5.zip)

**After adding the pulgin and the GXT jar**

Right-click on project.gwt.xml file Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT). This will add the gxt.jar to your classpath and module file and various GXT files to your war folder.

Once Ext GWT (GXT) has been added to your project several new Ext GWT (GXT) palette categories will appear:

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your GWT module file and right-click to select the Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT) command. This will add the gxt.jar to your classpath and module file and various GXT files to your war folder.

Once Ext GWT (GXT) has been added to your project several new Ext GWT (GXT) palette categories will appear:

Keep in mind though, that is for version 2.x.

GXT 3 is not compatible with the Google plugin For Eclipse, thus you won't be able to use the GWT Designer to manipulate GXT 3 widgets.

The Google plugin and GWT Designer are compatible only with GXT 2.2 and currently there are not active projects designated to provide support for GXT3, due to the GPE becoming an open-source.

Comment: i cannot find the option when i rt click on module file. Please see the image(edited in the question).

Comment: May you need to install  WindowBuilder Pro for eclipse.

Comment: i use this link to add windowbuilder Still its not working.
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.3/